How to make customized buttons from power apps work in sharepoint?
Is there any help i can use maybe a json format perhaps from sharepoint side, will trigger my buttons in sharepoint365 to work, if my button is submitting a document from flow, then this button should do the same in sharepoint. Are there any examples i can relate regarding this?
enter image description here

What exactly are the requirements here? Do you need help with creating a flow to upload document in SharePoint or something else?

@GaneshSanap-MVP yes i need help for creating a flow to upload document in sharepoint

Try solution given here: Uploading To A SharePoint Document Library From Power Apps. Let me know if it works for you.
